# How to show text which is retrived from database with newlines?

Tags: mysql, web

The text stored in db is like this:

Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum

But when displayed it appears like this:

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum

Can anyone give appropriate solution?

Comment: post the details of the column - type, collation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use funtion `nl2br()`
By using this function you will get desired output.

Syntax::

```
nl2br(string,xhtml);
```